# Using WebStorm for ECMAScript 2015 development without my own gulp/grunt/webpack scripting?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webstorm

Is it possible to use WebStorm for developing HTML+JS projects WITHOUT writing my own (more and more) complex configuration scripts for babel/gulp/grunt/webpack or similar tools?

I don't need complex frameworks (like Angular or React), but importing multiple ECMAScript 2015 files, debugging and deployment should still be possible.

I found several Settings in **WebStorm 2016.1.3**, and they seem to integrate some tools, but they do not seem to (automatically) establish a working development system comparable with Visual Studio?

**EDIT:**
I would like to see my web pages in chrome and debug JS in WebStorm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

current browser and nodejs not full support es2015 feactures, you can use polifil like babel and for using systemjs dependancies (in browser for create bundle) you need use webpack.
You can use pure javascript without any dependancies if feactures is supported, refer to https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: So the short version is: no, it is not possible?

Answer (score 1):

[You don't need gulp/grunt/etc.](https://pinboard.in/search/u:dandv?query=against+grunt)

WebStorm supports ES2015 just fine, and even [some ES2016 features (e.g. async/await)](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/06/webstorm-11-roadmap-discussion/#comment-225695). You don't even need to configure a file watcher. Just define the "node" executable to be `babel-node`.

[image: Run/Debug configuration for ES2016]

Comment: This seems to be for browser-less debugging with Node.js.